# Absolute positioning of UIElement in FlowDocument in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I want to add a `Button` control that appears on top of a `Hyperlink` control. Currently, the `Button` is part of a `FlowDocument` and appears next to the `Hyperlink`, but I want it to have absolute positioning so that it overlaps the `Hyperlink`. How can I achieve this?

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            The maximum speed is
            <Hyperlink>150</Hyperlink>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Button>No way!</Button>
            </InlineUIContainer>
            in this road!
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `StackPanel` to "stack" multiple objects that inherit from `UIElement`. `Hyperlink` doesn't inherit from `UIElement`, but you can get around this by placing the `Hyperlink` inside a `ContentControl`.

Here is a working example:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            The maximum speed is
            <StackPanel>
                <Button>No way!</Button>
                <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Hyperlink>150</Hyperlink>
                </ContentControl>
            </StackPanel>
            in this road!
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Edited code, with `Button` appearing on top (higher z-order) of the `Hyperlink` (see comments).

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            The maximum speed is
            <Grid>
                <Button>No way!</Button>
                <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Hyperlink>150</Hyperlink>
                </ContentControl>
            </Grid>
            in this road!
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want it to be over the hyperlink-

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to be "on top" so you can't see the hyperlink? If so, why do you need the hyperlink?

Comment: I want it to appear later when I the hyperlink! I have used Button for simplicity now! It will be Slider. The Hyperlink will be an integer value and when I click it a Slider will appear! That is my final goal!

Comment: If you use a Grid instead of a Stackpanel, then the UIElements will stack in the "z direction". You can alter which element is on top by changing the order of the elements. I have edited by answer to show what you need to do.